# registerForActivityResult execute function as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-permissions

I'm trying to implement a 2 different buttons in a fragment which get location in different ways and them both need to access location permission runtime (in newer versions above M), each have to do another action. I set listener that called WantedAction or WantedAction2 as needed.
my minimal basic code to demonstrate my question please:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment() {
    private val requestPermissionWantedActionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String> =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted)
                wantedAction()
        }

    private val requestPermissionWantedAction2Launcher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted)
                wantedAction2()
        }

    private fun requestLocationPermission(op: ActivityResultLauncher<String>) {
        val permission =
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
//tell user why this permission is needed
                op.launch(permission)
        } else {
            op.launch(permission)
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to send parameter to to `requestPermissionWantedActionLauncher` or `requestPermissionWantedAction2Launcher` in order to perform a function call whicl allowed me to combine them please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to merge them. What you could do to use only a single launcher is create a separate property that tells it what to do when granted.

```
private var postPermissionGrantedAction: (()->Unit)? = null
    
private val requestPermissionWantedActionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String> =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) postPermissionGrantedAction?.invoke()
    }

private fun requestLocationPermission() {
    val permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
        //tell user why this permission is needed
    }
    requestPermissionWantedActionLauncher.launch(permission)
}
```

Then whichever code calls your `requestLocationPermission` function should first set the property to the function that should be called, such as:

```
postLocationPermissionGrantedAction = ::wantedAction
requestLocationPermission()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

- Create a class **A** that extends `ActivityResultCallback<T>`
- Which will have a property **B** which will be another `ActivityResultCallback<T>`
- Use the **A** one time in `registerForActivityResult`
- Each time before launch, assign a lambda to the property(**B**) of **A**

This way you can pass whatever lambda you want at each time you launch(no need for flags).

Example:

```
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback

class CallBackWrapper<T> : ActivityResultCallback<T> {
    var callback: ActivityResultCallback<T>? = null

    /**
     * Called when the result is available
     */
    override fun onActivityResult(result: T?) {
        callback?.onActivityResult(result);
    }
}

singleWrapper: CallBackWrapper<Boolean> = CallBackWrapper<>()
```

In activity code:

```
activityResultSingleLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), singleWrapper)
singleWrapper.callback = {//your lambda}
activityResultSingleLauncher.launch(permission)
```

It should be something like above(I can't access my own code at the moment, so let me know if you face errors).

Comment: can you add a code example which shows the basic idea here please?

Comment: Edited the answer @IdanB